# Route params to controller

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm studying the MVC pattern to improve my coding skills, as an exercise, I'm writing this route system to map actions and parameters to the relative controllers. I've tested the code and it's working great, but I can't understand how to map multiple parameters to a controller. Here is my code, can anyone suggest me a better way to do this?

```php
<?php
if( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ){
  $requested_uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    if( $requested_uri === '' ){
      echo $controller->index();
    }
    elseif( $requested_uri != '' ){
      $requested_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

      $class = (string) ucfirst($requested_uri[1]).'Controller';
      $method = (string) $requested_uri[2];

      if( isset($requested_uri[3]) && class_exists($class) ){
        $param = (string) $requested_uri[3];
        $obj = new $class;
        echo $obj->$method($param);
      }
      else{
        if( class_exists( $class ) ){
          $obj = new $class;
          echo $obj->$method();
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution code is here :

```
<?php
if( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ){
  $requested_uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    if( $requested_uri === '' ){
      echo $controller->index();
    }
    elseif( $requested_uri != '' ){
      $requested_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

      $class = (string) ucfirst($requested_uri[1]).'Controller';
      $method = (string) $requested_uri[2];

      //-----  below part is my idea ... 
      $params = array();

      for($i=3 ; $i<=count(requested_uri) ; $i++ ){
            $params = requested_uri[$i];
      }

      $controllerInstance = new $class();
      call_user_func_array(array($controllerInstance , $method) , $params);

      //---- end part
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: instead of the `for()` loop, isn't better to use a `foreach()`?